# Alinhar controles com bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho essa view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ExcelFinancing";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .embaixo {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 20%;
            width: auto;
            bottom: auto;
            top: 50%;
            margin: 10%,10%,10%,10%;
        }

        radio .btn,
        .radio-inline .btn {
            padding-left: 2em;
            min-width: 7em;
        }



        .radio label,
        .radio-inline label {
            text-align: left;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header fa-align-center">@ViewBag.TitlePage</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="panel panel-default">*@

    @using (Html.BeginForm("geraExcel1", "FinancingReport", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Label("De")
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataIni, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ID = "dataIni" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dataIni, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Label("Até")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataFim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ID = "dataFim" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dataFim, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="well well-sm col-md-10">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Male", true, new { id = "IsMale", name="status", value="Todos" })
                        Todos
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female", new { id = "IsFemale", name = "status", value = "Ativo" })
                        Ativo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female", new { id = "IsFemale", name = "status", value = "Inativo" })
                        Inativo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Gerar Relatório" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
       </div>

            }

    </body>
</html>
```

Alterei o código da view para esse código. A questão toda é a seguinte:
1) O botão submit está ficando em cima dos radiobuttons e ao lado dos calendários.

2) Os radiobuttons não estão dando distância entre eles e os calendários.

Veja o screenshot abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Roda o que? Não seria melhor vc postar o código HTML já como é renderizado na página do que o código em ASP. Da forma como está vc limita muito as pessoas que podem te responder. E qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando a 3 ou a 4 ?

Comment: @hugocsl, como eu pego já renderizado? Usando o debug do navegador? Copiar aquele código e postar?

Comment: Isso mesmo jovem, pega aquele código e mais o CSS que usou, e diga a versão do Bootstrap. Acho que isso vai te ajudar muito a conseguir uma resposta de forma mais rápida, afinal com o seu código não é possível simular o seu problema para poder te ajudar. Inclusive um print da tela com o problema tb seria muito útil nesse tipo de pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Para usar o Grid do Bootsrap vc deve seguir algumas regras da documentação como vc pode consultar aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid Se vc não seguir o "manual" não tem como o seu Grid ficar certo...

Repare que vc deve precisa de um `.container` para englobar o conteúdo, e depois vc precisa separa os seus grupos de conteúdo em `.ROW`s que por sua vez devem estar dentro das suas colunas `col-md-*` para vc não ter problemas de responsividade depois.

Ajustando esses detalhes no Grid o seu layout vai ficar como o esperado e como vc pode ver abaixo.

```css
.embaixo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20%;
    width: auto;
    /* bottom: auto; */
    top: 50%;
    margin: 10%,10%,10%,10%;
}

.radio .btn,
.radio-inline .btn {
    padding-left: 2em;
    min-width: 7em;
}



.radio label,
.radio-inline label {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="page-header fa-align-center">@ViewBag.TitlePage</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("geraExcel1", "FinancingReport", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            @Html.Label("De")
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="date" name="" id="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            @Html.Label("Até")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="date" name="" id="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="well well-sm col-md-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Male", true, new { id = "IsMale", name="status",
                            value="Todos"
                            })
                            Todos
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female", new { id = "IsFemale", name = "status", value =
                            "Ativo" })
                            Ativo
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female", new { id = "IsFemale", name = "status", value =
                            "Inativo" })
                            Inativo
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="submit" value="Gerar Relatório" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```